# Erro banner Bootstrap Site HTML Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theme, bootstrap-4

Meu site publicado no wordpress contém um seguinte problema, quando eu diminuo a tela do meu navegador, e clico nas 3 barras do meu navbar para abrir o menu, a imagem tenta acompanhar o navbar, fazendo assim a imagem se esticar. Como mostra as imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A img se estica depois de apertar o botão do navbar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O link de acesso para ver o html é: [link site](http://ndp.flf.edu.br)

Comment: Amigo sem o seu CSS e a sua estrutura do html fica complicado te responder. Se vc tiver ao menos um link da página edite sua pergunta com ele. Sem saber se essa imagem é um Background, um uma tag IMG não da para te responder com precisão.

Comment: desculpas, o link para acesso é http://ndp.flf.edu.br

Comment: Cara coloca lá a imagem pq entrei agora e está sem...

Comment: já está ajeitado com a imagem acabei de coloca-la, desculpe ^^